# Azure App Service Editor (Monaco) stoped working / no access http error 500.1001

Tags: azure, version-control, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-monaco

i cant access anymore to azure App Service Editor (monaco) , every thing was ok , and than just stopped. The web site is working, and i can access using visual studio but not online

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about App Service Editor(formerly known as Visual Studio Online (Monaco))? To access the editor, go to App Service Editor (Preview) in the Development Tools section of the left-hand navigation of your app and see if that works.

Comment: Can you access Kudu (yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net)? Are you seeing this on all sites or one? Please clarify your question (and the title!) as it's not descriptive enough in its current form.

Comment: @Ashok yes i am speaking about visual studio online , same App service editor . the problem is that i cant access to App Service Editor  , it was working for 10 month , and just stoped .

Comment: @DavidEbbo yes i can access to kudu  (yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) , but when i try to access to to the  App Service Editor  (yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev) , i recieve an error message

Comment: What about if you create a blank new test app? Do you get the same behavior? Please share name of one such app so we can investigate

Comment: @DavidEbbo i using my company account , and have no access to create a new app , and it have that the server team reposnsible is traveling . 
basicly the system was stable for 10 months ,
now every thing is working except  when i try to acess to https://........scm.azurewebsites.net/dev the app service editor , i get the authentification window , the once i try to sign in it keeps loding for 3 min then a HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error 
the picture shows every thing , should i ask my it team to contact the microsoft support team ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help much without knowing the app that's at stake.

Comment: You could create an [Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for deep help.

Answer (score 1):

i had to stop the service and restart it , and it went to work again , still have no explanantion why it went wrong